# How to to switch my angular website from English to Spanish with a radio button?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a angular website where I select a language and press the next button and it changes my text to that language for all the the pages following for example if I click Spanish all the text on the next screen is Spanish and so on...

```
<div class="container tb-10">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(langForm)" #langForm="ngForm">
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <h4>Please select a language:</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="language" #lang value="e" ngModel> English&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </label><br>

                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="language" #lang value="s" ngModel> Spanish&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Para continuar en Español, por favor seleccione Español.</h4>
                </div>     
                <div>
                    <!-- Add this line where you want to show the error message -->
                    <p *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</p>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <button id="exit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" >Exit</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="navigateIfYes(lang)"> Next </button>
        </footer>
    </form>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-language-select',
  templateUrl: './language-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./language-select.component.css']
})
export class LanguageSelectComponent {

constructor(private router: Router) {}

errorMessage?: string;

navigateIfYes(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  if(input.classList.contains('ng-untouched')) {
    this.errorMessage = 'Please click on one of the option buttons above 
before submitting form!'
  } else {
    this.errorMessage = undefined
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/government");
  }
}

ngOnInit(): void {}

onSubmit(form: NgForm){
  console.log(form);
 }

}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview

Answer (score 0):

I recommand ngx-translate, since it's more friendly use than i18n from angular.

You need to put all your labels in a json file by language and in your html do something like:

```
<div>
  <p translate>{{label.paragraph-one}}</p>
</div>
```

and you can do a json file like this:

```
{
    "label":
    {
      "paragraph-one" : "something to translate"
    }
}
```

P.s.: With the last angular, you just need to import the translation file from json instead or using a service like this in the module:

```
import englishJSON from 'src/assets/i18n/english.json';
import spanishJSON from 'src/assets/i18n/spanish.json';
...
export class AppModule {
  public constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService.setTranslation('en', englishJSON , true);
    this.translateService.setTranslation('es', spanishJSON , true);
    this.translateService.use('en');
  }
}
```

And then to switch the translation, you put in a button this call:

```
translate.use('en'); or 
translate.use('es');
```

Comment: Can you make a quick example of how my json file should look?

Comment: and How that apply to my code above when I click next button and it convert everything to spanish. @JFPicard

Comment: @QuisDaCoder Same as the english one for the json file.

Comment: I never done json file thats why I'm asking

Comment: Updated for an example of json file